# How to enable logging for Redlock.Net?

Tags: c#, redis, log4net, liblog

I am using redlock library from below location.

https://github.com/samcook/RedLock.net

Below command returns with timeout only on production and it works on other environments.

```
RedLockFactory.Create
```

Using ILSpy i can see they have logged some lines during process and GetLogger() method is uses below code.

```
new StackFrame(1, false).DeclaringType;
```

I am hoping that, with some configuration changes, I can enable logging for this so that we dont have to redeploy any build. But I dont know how. Can you please help?

Answer (score 0):

To use log4net, adding below configuration enabled log.

```
<appender name="MyRollingFileAppender" type="log4net.Appender.RollingFileAppender">
    <file value="$(dataFolder)/logs/Mylog.txt" />
    <appendToFile value="true"/>
    <rollingStyle value="Size" />
    <maximumFileSize value="10MB" />
    <staticLogFileName value="true" />
    <maxSizeRollBackups value="10" />
    <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
        <header value="DateTime | Thread | Level | ClassName | Message&#13;&#10;" />
        <conversionPattern value="%date | %thread | %-5level | %logger | %message%newline" />
    </layout>
</appender>
<appender name="ConsoleAppender" type="log4net.Appender.ConsoleAppender">
    <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
        <conversionPattern value="%date | %thread | %-5level | %logger | %message%newline" />
    </layout>
</appender>
<root>
    <level value="ALL" />
    <appender-ref ref="MyRollingFileAppender" />
    <appender-ref ref="ConsoleAppender" />
</root>
```

You can check more examples [here](https://github.com/damianh/LibLog/tree/master/src).

Answer (score 0):

When you want to create a RedLock by using **RedLockFactory.Create**, you can pass a **loggerFactory** object to this method.

```
 var loggerFactory = LoggerFactory.Create(b => b.AddConsole()) ;
 var lock =  RedLockFactory.Create(endpoints, loggerFactory);
```

[image]

If you need more information, logging minimum level can be set.

```
var loggerFactory = LoggerFactory.Create(b => b.SetMinimumLevel(LogLevel.Trace).AddConsole());
```